# Select (focus) one form from multiple forms (same form) in visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have multiple instances of the same form open, I want to select one instance of that form to get focused. So I made an combo-box which lists all the titles of that form with different names thus when I select one title coming from the combo-box It should get focused and be in front.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Customers).Any Then
        MessageBox.Show("Opened")
        'code to select the form from the .text 
        '->
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to create a `List(Of Form)` and as you are populating your ComboBox with the form names, you can add each of the forms to a list. Then when you click on, say, item 0 in your ComboBox, the form at index 0 in the list of forms could be focused - like this maybe?

```
'put this in your main declarations
Dim ListOfForms As New List(Of Form)

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListOfForms(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListOfForms.Clear()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(frm1.Name)
    ListOfForms.Add(frm1)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(frm2.Name)
    ListOfForms.Add(frm2)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(frmX.Name)
    ListOfForms.Add(frmX)
End Sub
```